# Change GPU priority of a process under Windows

Tags: process, gpu, priority

Is it possible to change the GPU priority of a certain process under Windows 7 (and older versions if possible)?

Changing the CPU priority doesn't seem to have any effect on the GPU usage. I have a program doing some maths on the GPU, but i want it to use only idle GPU cycles.

Comment: which GPU do you have?

Comment: It shouldn't matter... but i have a nvidia geforce 9500 gt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The GPU is not directly controlled by the operating system, so the same type of multitasking available for CPUs is simply not available for GPUs. If there is any multitasking support for your GPU, it would be controlled by the graphics card driver.

Generally speaking, however, a GPU operation runs until it is done; the driver may only be able to interrupt the operation.