# Why is VLC Player unable to keep up with decoding a video when another program is using CPU, even though it's low priority?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, priority

I'm running ffmpeg on Windows 7 to re-encode some videos to x265. While it's running I want to watch some other videos in VLC Player (also x265-encoded, so decoding them takes a lot of CPU, too). I find that when I do this VLC Player is unable to decode it in time - the video pauses all the time and most of the screen is smudged with gray. It's completely unwatchable. (The videos play fine when ffmpeg is not running.)

The ffmpeg process uses all available CPU time, but it runs with "idle" priority. VLC Player runs with "normal" priority (I even tried "high"). I thought this should allow VLC Player to use all the CPU time it needs and only the remaining time should go to the "idle" priority process. Why isn't this happening?

Comment: Why are you so sure it's a CPU issue?  Video encoding and decoding is typically handed off to the GPU in a properly configured PC.

Comment: See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/gpu-preemption

Comment: Interesting point! I was assuming it's a CPU issue, because ffmpeg uses as much CPU as it can get and VLC Player also uses quite a lot (~45%). IO priority made no difference, either. According to https://superuser.com/questions/516948/change-gpu-priority-of-a-process-under-windows there is no way to set GPU priority, so am I screwed then? I basically cannot encode and view x265 videos at the same time?